# Go to next row when HTML table is full

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, html-table

I am using an HTML table to display data from a MySQL table using PHP. I need it so once the table has 10 columns, it will move on to the next row.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

echo '<table width="100%" border="1px"><tr width="100%">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
                    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
<?php
}
echo "</tr></table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Simple: use a counter. Please use your logic, otherwise you won't get far if you stump on such basic tasks.

Comment: modulus, hopefully some one will find one of the many duplicates for this

Comment: `$i = 0; $i++; if($i > 9): else: endif;`.

Comment: Seems like there should be lots of dupes, but I can't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but something like this should work or get you started in a good direction:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

echo '<table width="100%" border="1px"><tr width="100%">';

$x=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    if($x==0){      
        echo "<tr>\n";

    }elseif($x%10){
        echo"</tr><tr>\n";
    }
    ?>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
    <?php
    $x++;       
}
echo "</tr></table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Glad it worked.  Can I get a check mark on this answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter to your loop starting at one.

Each time through the loop if the remainder after dividing the counter value by 10 is 1 
add the `<tr>`.  If the remainder is 0 then add a `</tr>`   Then after the loop a `</tr>` if the remainder is not evenly divisible by 10.

```
<?php
echo '<table width="100%" border="1px"><tr width="100%">';
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $i++;
?>
    <?php if ($i%10 ==1): ?><tr><?php endif; ?>
    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
    <?php if ($i%10 ==0): ?></tr><?php endif; ?>
<?php
}
if ($i%10 != 0) echo "</tr>";
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using modulo (%)**

After each 10th cell, if a new cell is added, the current row is closed and a new row is opened first, before outputting the cell.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

echo '<table width="100%" border="1px"><tr>';

$cell = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($cell++ % 10 == 0 && $cell > 1)
  {
?>
                    </tr><tr>
<?php
  }

?>
                    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
<?php
}
echo "</tr></table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The extra condition `&& $cell > 1` seems to be a little odd, but without it, you will get an empty row to start with. Eliminating it by putting `++` before `$cell` will cause the first row to be 9 cells instead of 10. Putting `$cell > 0 &&` in front of the modulo will cause cell never to be incremented, because the first part of the expression is always false. Moving the `if` to execute it after outputting the cell, would cause the risk of ending with an empty row. It could be solved using a `do..while` loop, but you'd have to check up front if you have one row at least.

Long story short: use the code above. :)

**Using a simple counter and reset it after each row**

I think it's even more readable without the modulo, though you'd have to initialize `$cell` to -1 to prevent the first row to be 9 cells. Nevertheless, I think this is cleaner:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

echo '<table width="100%" border="1px"><tr>';

$cell = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  if (++$cell == 10)
  {
    $cell = 0;
?>
                    </tr><tr>
<?php
  }

?>
                    <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
<?php
}
echo "</tr></table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
                  <?php 
                  $endRow = 0;
                  $columns = 10; // number of columns
                  $hloopRow1 = 0;
                  do { 
                  if($endRow == 0  && $hloopRow1++ != 0) echo "<tr>";
                  ?>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php  $endRow++; if($endRow >= $columns) { ?>       
                  </tr>
                    <?php $endRow = 0;  }
                    } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

                    if($endRow != 0) {
                        while ($endRow < $columns) {
                            echo("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
                            $endRow++;
                        }
                    echo("</tr>");
                    }
                    ?>      
</table>
```

This should work fine. Hope this helps.