# javascript how to add a row every forth cell?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

i'm creating a table with javascript. i want my table to have 4 cells in one row, so 5th cell would be in new row.

if i have 10 objects to display on the cells, i would have 2 full rows and 1 row with only 2cells.

here's the code that i have. any idea??

```
var a = { style: ["1","2","3","4", "5","6"]};

var oldTable = document.getElementById('example'),
newTable = oldTable.cloneNode();

var b = a.style.length;
for (var i= 0; i <= 4; i++){
    if (b >= 4) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        var k = "";
    for(var j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width="175px";
        div.style.height="250px";

        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a.style[k++]));
        td.appendChild(div);
        tr.appendChild(td);
           }
    }
newTable.appendChild(tr);
}
oldTable.parentNode.replaceChild(newTable, oldTable);
```

Comment: What is the error or problem? I.e. how does this break?

Comment: this would only copy the first cell and have 6cells instead of add a new row...

Comment: Are you aware that you are missing one `}`? Try indenting your code correctly -- after that its much easier to spot!

Comment: Not sure the purpose of the outer for loop? Also trying to increment k, though its initialized to "".

Comment: i wanted to make maximum 5 rows, and create a row after every 4th cell.. can any guide me with this?

Comment: This question is very similar to this one:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821083/go-to-next-row-when-html-table-is-full/17821196#17821196][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821083/go-to-next-row-when-html-table-is-full/17821196#17821196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your outer loop entirely as well as the `if`.  Then you mainly just need this:

```
if(j%4 == 0 && j != 0){
    newTable.appendChild(tr);
    tr = document.createElement('tr');        
}
```

This will start a new row every 4 records.

http://jsfiddle.net/X5g2p/1/

Comment: one more question! this would create rows under a row. is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by rows under a row.  I did make one small change to avoid creating a first empty row.

Comment: i have another question. would this function work if the var a = [{"style":"1","color":"WHITE","price":"$1.00"}, {"style":"2","color":"BLACK","price":"$1.00"}]? i tried but i was not able to get it work properly.

Comment: If you change the structure of your object you will have to change your code.